# Selenium testing on Frames

Tags: java, selenium, selenium-webdriver, selenium-chromedriver

I am trying to learn Selenium from Youtube. I have written the simple code below on Frames. I want to click on `linkText` which is not visible but manually can scroll and click on it. I am trying with the below code but getting the error:

```
org.openqa.selenium.WebDriverException: unknown error: Element is not clickable
```

My code:

```
public class Frame_Test {

    WebDriver driver;

    @Test
    public void test1() {

        System.setProperty("webdriver.chrome.driver", "C:\\chromedriver_win32\\chromedriver.exe");
        ChromeOptions options = new ChromeOptions();
        options.addArguments("--start-maximized");
        driver = new ChromeDriver(options);

        driver.get("http://seleniumhq.github.io/selenium/docs/api/java/index.html");
        driver.manage().timeouts().implicitlyWait(10,TimeUnit.SECONDS);

        driver.switchTo().frame("packageListFrame");
        driver.findElement(By.linkText("org.openqa.selenium.safari")).click();

    }

}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can scroll down with screen height using this code:

```
JavascriptExecutor js = (JavascriptExecutor)driver;
js.executeScript("window.scrollTo(0, document.body.scrollHeight);");
```

Scrolling down for some number of pixels:

```
js.executeScript("scroll(0, 300);");
```

Scrolling up for some number of pixels:

```
js.executeScript("scroll(0, -300);");
```

Hope it helps you!

Comment: Hi Ratmir, Thanks for ur response.. The above script is working but it is scrolling to the end and i cant click the webelements which are in the middle of the list... Iam sure there is some logic to move the scroll anywhere we want... Iam not expert in code, just trying to learn... can you please tell me to move the scroll anywhere we want...

Comment: @user3297196, if my answer was helpful -- check a tick near my answer, please.

Answer (score 0):

You can use the below method:

```
public static void scrollToElement(By elementToken, WebDriver driver){
    WebElement element = driver.findElement(elementToken);
    ((JavascriptExecutor) driver).executeScript("arguments[0].scrollIntoView(true);", element);
    try {
        Thread.sleep(1000);
    } catch (InterruptedException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}
```

Or if you don't want to use the explicit method you can use the scroll code in your code:

```
driver.get("http://seleniumhq.github.io/selenium/docs/api/java/index.html";
driver.manage().timeouts().implicitlyWait(10,TimeUnit.SECONDS);

driver.switchTo().frame("packageListFrame");

WebElement element = driver.findElement(By.linkText("org.openqa.selenium.safari"));((JavascriptExecutor) driver).executeScript("arguments[0].scrollIntoView(true);", element);

driver.findElement(By.linkText("org.openqa.selenium.safari")).click();
```